# libbson-1.0.0.dylib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator error is displays when trying to run project after adding mongoSwift driver from Github

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mongodb, swift-package-manager

I added swift package dependency mongoSwift driver to my Xcode project when I run my project the error is displaying as:

> Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mongo-c-driver/lib/libbson-1.0.0.dylib" Reason: libbson-1.0.0.dylib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the library's deployment target is not higher than your project's target and that you have compatible xcode versions

Answer (score 0):

Mangoswift only supports macOS and Linux.

> We only support MacOS
>   and Linux. [[1]](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-swift-driver/issues/117)

Comment: Yes I was trying to use for iOS apps.Thank you for your response.